# SQL date number

Tags: sql

I want to do the following:

```
Select 
username,
(select min(sub.date) from data sub where sub.username = outer.username) as firstDate,
date,
? as dateSequence
from data as outer;
```

I don't know what to put in for dateSequence. This value should represent where the 'date' value is in the sequence of all the days the customer is in the database (so the value of firstDate will be 1 etc).

Is there any way I can do this? The customers miss out dates and have multiple entries per date. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `the sequence of all the days the customer is in the database` is terribly unclear. If the customer's first appearance in the database was 1 Jan 2012 and today is 1 Jan 2013, would the correct value be 365?

Comment: Apologies. No the value would be 1, because it would be 'day #1' for that customer.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the days"?

Comment: Customer places orders on Jan 1 (twice), June 10, Feb 23rd of the following year. These dates should be assigned 1,2 and 3 for 'dateSequence'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: OK, that is clearer. But  you mean "These orders" not "these dates".

Comment: Yes. The orders should be assigned a 'date sequence' number. The idea is to be able to pull out a customers first 5, or first 10 order days, not first 5, or first 10 orders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select username,
       select min(date) over (partition by username) as firstDate,
       date,
       row_number() over (partition by username order by date) as date_sequence
from data as outer;
```

Comment: . . You should replace the subquery with `MIN() over` as well.

Comment: Not only are you guys crackerjack SQL coders, you are *$*%#@ mindreaders.

Comment: This answer works fine, but 'proc sql' in SAS won't allow 'over' or 'parition'. Not great!

Comment: @user2146441: what is "SAS"? You should have stated your DBMS in the initial question.

Comment: SAS is a stats package. https://www.sas.com/ Is there a way to do the above with a subselect or subquery rather than using the 'over' and 'partition' keywords.